# C++ Windows Service socket connection error

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, service

I wrote a win32 test application with re-usable unit to port to a service. The test application runs perfectly. It opens a socket to the device(s) to communicate with the device.

Now when running the service, I get a socket connection error. I've tried setting the logon account to Administrator and Local System account with desktop interaction but still get the socket connection error.

I compile the win32 app and all work fine .... any ideas on what else I can try?

Comment: What is the connection error, can you give the error number?

Answer (score 2):

Sockets are not affected by user accounts.  That is one reason they are useful in services.  I use sockets in services all the time and they work fine.  The cause of the problem is more likely a bug in your socket code instead.